# How to get count?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I want to get counts of site id based on some condition. The conditions are given below:

- In every 5 minutes we are uploading data into db.
- If we are not receiving any data within 6 minutes we will consider as 1 data string is missing.
- Like that if we are not receiving the data for the last 1 hour then we can say that  10 data string are missing

**I want calculate the count of missing string of each site id in between two dates.**

**Sample DB:**

```
Sl_No  Site_Id  Uploaded_Data  Uploaded_Date
-----  -------  -------------  -------------
 1      ST001       xyz        4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM
 2      ST002       xyz        4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM
 3      ST003       xyz        4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM
 4      ST001       xyz        4/30/2015 5:52:36 PM
 5      ST002       xyz        4/30/2015 5:53:20 PM
 6      ST003       xyz        4/30/2015 5:54:25 PM
 7      ST001       xyz        4/30/2015 5:57:15 PM
 8      ST002       xyz        4/30/2015 5:58:25 PM
 9      ST003       xyz        4/30/2015 6:00:25 PM
 10     ST001       xyz        4/30/2015 6:02:05 PM
 11     ST002       xyz        4/30/2015 6:03:30 PM
 12     ST003       xyz        4/30/2015 6:05:25 PM
```

Based on the above condition I have to get the count as given below:

```
SiteID Count
------ -----
ST001   0
ST002   1
ST003   2
```

Please help me to find a proper solution. I am newbie in sql and c#.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server or mysql or oracle or db2?? which one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Group By clause to get your result through SQL.

```
SELECT SiteID, Count(*) as Count FROM Table WHERE Uploaded_Date BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2
```

This will give you a list of SiteID and the Count based on your where condition. Further if you need to find the missing count, you can do a subtraction to find the missing count.

E.g. If you are trying to find the missing count for an hour and your upload interval is 5 minutes, then you know that the count should be 12, through a simple math operation Total Minutes / 5. Use this count of 12 to subtract from the count available in the table.

```
SELECT SiteID, (DATEDIFF ( minute , startdate , enddate ) / 5) - Count(*) as MissingCount FROM Table WHERE Uploaded_Date BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

Comment: But How can I get the count of site id based on uploaded time difference is  greater than 5 minute.

Comment: @Reshma You have two time intervals, E.g. 10:30 and 10:45. In a best case this should have uploaded 3 times in a 5 minute interval. Instead of trying to find records within the 5 minute interval, you can search your database for 3 entries for the site id, between 10:30 and 10:45.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose - what if those 3 records were inserted at 10:43,10:44 and 10,45. your query will give no missing count whereas OP would need to show 2 missing count

Comment: @Praveen : If I have more than 100 sites in db. It may diificult to select specific site id to filter.

Comment: @Reshma What filter are you referring to. Could you explain?

Comment: @ughai Agreed, however the OP has stated that there will be an upload every 5 minutes. So you ideally could not have 10:43, 10:44 and 10.45 as entries.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose : typed by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` and a self join to get your result. Something like this. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9ca2/1)

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(Sl_No  INT, Site_Id  CHAR(5),Uploaded_Data  CHAR(3),Uploaded_Date DATETIME)

insert into @table values

 (1      ,'ST001'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM'),
 (2      ,'ST002'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM'),
 (3      ,'ST003'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM'),
 (4      ,'ST001'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:52:36 PM'),
 (5      ,'ST002'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:53:20 PM'),
 (6      ,'ST003'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:54:25 PM'),
 (7      ,'ST001'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:57:15 PM'),
 (8      ,'ST002'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 5:58:25 PM'),
 (9      ,'ST003'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 6:00:25 PM'),
 (10     ,'ST001'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 6:02:05 PM'),
 (11     ,'ST002'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 6:03:30 PM'),
 (12     ,'ST003'       ,'xyz'        ,'4/30/2015 6:05:25 PM');
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '4/30/2015 5:47:25 PM', @endDate = '4/30/2015 6:05:25 PM'
 ;WITH CTE AS 
 (
 SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY site_id ORDER BY Uploaded_Date) rn
 FROM @table
 WHERE Uploaded_Date Between @startDate AND @endDate
 )
 SELECT C1.site_id,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,C1.Uploaded_Date,C2.Uploaded_Date) > 5 THEN  DATEDIFF(minute,C1.Uploaded_Date,C2.Uploaded_Date)/5 ELSE 0 END) as mindiff
 FROM CTE C1
 INNER JOIN CTE C2
 ON C1.rn + 1 = C2.rn
 AND C1.site_id = C2.site_id
 GROUP BY C1.site_id
```

Comment: How to add this condition on the above query  Where Uploaded_Date Between startDate AND endDate

Comment: @ughai.Here you direcltiy given the date.How can  I read datetime from testboxes used in my page.

Comment: You can pass these values to your `SqlCommand` using [parameters](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06).

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a try:

```
SELECT Site_ID,COUNT(*)
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Uploaded_Date,GETDATE()) <= 60
GROUP BY Site_ID
HAVING DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MAX(Uploaded_Date),GETDATE()) >= 6
```

Getting back all sites where there is one or more rows that are 6 or more minutes old; and a count where they are no more than 60 minutes old.